# Ajax request with bootstrap modal in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display some information in a bootstrap modal based on some values.

Here is the work flow

1.Display Hyperlinks in a loop with a title.

2.When click on each hyperlink grabs the id value.

3.Make ajax request with these id as parameter and show the response in bootstrap model.

1.**display hyperlinks**

```
//display the hyperlinks in a loop
    <?php $i=0;foreach($services as $service) {?>
      <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"  data-id="<?php echo $service->services_id;  ?>" class="btn-block"><?php echo $service->services_title; ?></a>
    <?php $i++;}?>
```

2.**grabs the id value and make ajaxrequest**

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(){
            var id=$(this).data('id');
            //undefined
            alert(id);
            //shows loading text
            //it dosent work
    $('.data-modal').html('loading');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Functions/form_process.php?action=getdetailsbyid',
        data:{id: id},
        success: function(data) {
          $('.data-modal').html(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
         });
        });
```

The problem is cant get the id value,`alert(id)` returns `undefined` also `$('.data-modal').html('loading')` is not shown

**modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">THIS IS A SAMPLE POPUP 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            <strong>services.</strong>        
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: what you are returning in form_process.php file ?

Comment: some text data,but i cant grab the `id` value

Comment: you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by defintiion

Comment: ok so how will i solve this issue

Comment: `$(this)` wont work in your code, you need to use an identifier or change the method you are invoking.  [Example](http://www.bootply.com/ipVBWogSYD)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `foreach` outputs links like this:

```
 <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="123" class="btn-block">title</a>
 <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1234567" class="btn-block">another title</a>
```

You could then invoke the `click` method instead of `show.bs.modal` in order to use `$(this)`.

So your code will change to:

```
 $('.btn-block').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
    $('.modal-body').html('loading');

       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Functions/form_process.php?action=getdetailsbyid',
        data:{id: id},
        success: function(data) {
          $('.modal-body').html(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
          alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
 });
```

**[Here is an Example](http://www.bootply.com/TGOCaX68ic)**

---

Otherwise you will need to use a unique id on all your outputted links (which you can do using a counter in your `foreach`)

Comment: @Shammon did the above work ..am in the same situation