# can't show the modal in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter, and i want to show the detail data in modal, the detail data is from another table.

I have a button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="detail_barang(&quot;<?php echo $tbrang->id_barang;?>&quot;)">Detail</button>
```

And this is my detail_barang function:

```
function detail_barang(id)
{
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

  $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('admin/Barang/barang/ajax_detail_barang/')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#modal_detail').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Detail Barang'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Kesalahan!');
    }



    });
}
```

Modal Script:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_detail">
<div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Detail Barang</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
            <thead id="tblHead">
              <tr>
                <th>ID Barang</th>
                <th>No Inv</th>
                <th class="text-right">Kondisi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($detail_barang as $detil)
                {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $detil->id_barang ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $detil->no_inv ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $detil->kondisi ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

ajax_detail_barang function:

```
public function ajax_detail_barang($id)
{
    $where = array
    (
        'id_barang' => $id,
        'kondisi' => 'Ada'
    );

    $data['detail_barang'] = $this->modelku->get_by_id('detail_barang', $where)->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

get_by_id function:

```
public function get_by_id($table, $where)
{
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

But when i click the button, the error appears "Kesalahan!" whats wrong my code?

Comment: Have you verified you're sending your request to the proper url? You should probably also post the `get_by_id()` method

Comment: how can i do that? pls explain the code or give me a reference. Thank you

Comment: You can check using your browser's dev tools (F12 in chrome, under network tab for exampe). Check where your request is going and what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see is in how u are using the returned data from ur model

```
public function get_by_id($table, $where)
{
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->row();
//at this point it already contains the data u need
}
```

but here u are using result();

```
$data['detail_barang'] = $this->modelku->get_by_id('detail_barang', $where)->result();
//i tried and u cant use result method if u already executed row method.
```

In short, remove **result()**

Hope my answer helps u.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I already remove the result() but the problem is appear from my view, like this: Undefined variable: detail_barang Line Number: 134 I think i already declare the ['detail_barang'] in here: `$data['detail_barang'] = $this->modelku->get_by_id('detail_barang', $where);` What's wrong my code? pls help me. Thx

Comment: Ok so i saw one prblem, the other one is that in your modal u are writing php code, and u wanna fill the info on that modal after executing a javascript function, u should manipulate the dom content with javascript.
Check this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458705/ajax-request-with-bootstrap-modal-in-php)