# PHP - display query search results in Bootstrap modal window

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I have code below for a search bar that, upon clicking 'Search', loads a new page with the query results. How do I change it so instead of loading a new page, the query results open in a modal popup within the same page?

**index.php**

```
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
  </form>
</body>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);

  include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
      $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
    }else{
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
        $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
        $audio_name = $row['audio'];
        $output .= "<a href='audio/$audio_name'>$audio_name</a> ";
      }
    }
    echo $output;
  }else{
    "Please add search parameter";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: jQuery AJAX or XMLHTTPRequest should help you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458705/ajax-request-with-bootstrap-modal-in-php) question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript on your page to executed an AJAX call to search.php. That PHP file preferable returns JSON data, or complete HTML that can be added to the modal window.

Conceptually:

1. Use JavaScript to executed AJAX POST to search.php
2. Have search.php return the data in JSON format.
3. Have JavaScript catch the returned data, iterate through it and create HTML elements.
4. Use JavaScript to open a new modal window.
5. Use JavaScript to add the HTML elements to the modal's body.

You don't necessarily need to use JavaScript to create the modal window. You can create it in plain HTML and fill it and open it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Here's my solution for that, so first, you have to capture the form submission, the technique is doing `GET` request using jQuery which I assume you already using jQuery since you are using bootstrap and bootstrap uses jQuery

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault() // do not submit form
    // do get request
    $.get( 'search.php', { q : },function(e){
        // then show the modal first
        $('#mymodal').modal('show');
        // then put the results there
        $('#mymodal:visible .modal-container .modal-body').html(e);
    });
});
```